# IE is not firing ajax call in jquery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have this code that it is working on firefox and chrome, but in IE8/IE7 it's not working.
The server is not been reached ever.

```
$("#adicionarItem").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: $("#formAdicionaItem").attr("action"),
        data: $("#formAdicionaItem").serialize(),
        success: function(result){
            //do something
        }
    });
});
```

Does anyone has any idea what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is there any change if you set

```
cache: false,
```

I know IE has a habit of caching GET requests.

Comment: Can we see the page in question or some more code? Do you see any requests going out in Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) after you click the button in IE?